# How do I make firefox default to google search for strings that are not real domains?

Tags: firefox

When user the urlBar to search for something like `mock.patch.object` I do not really expect to get an error about a non existing domain.

Instead I expect to get google search results.

Apparently this issue happens if the first word has at least one dot in it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think its by-design for Firefox. As a workaround, add keywords for a specific search engine in settings `about:preferences#search`.

Answer (score 0):

Search with double quotes string like : "mock.patch.object"

Default search engine will search for the specific string inside the " ".

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to be forced to do this, I almost always copy/paste code from somewhere, adding quotes would kill the workflow.

Comment: Paste the string in the search bar , not in the url bar.